# how to calculate moving average which exclude previous set of values

Tags: python, pandas, average

I am trying find something resembles a moving average but excludes the previous set of values
Below snapshot of excel sheet shows the average with a window of 2.

[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Rc7W.png)

I tried using rolling and expand command in pandas but they include the previous value.
Are there any other methods that can be used from pandas

Comment: Can you give an example of "a moving average that excludes the previous set of values"? I'm not 100% sure about what it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way of doing this is to convert the column to a list and then calculate the moving averages using a loop (or more precisely a "list comprehension").

```
# Creating a DataFrame (like the one you have)
values_col = [i * 10 for i in range(10)]
df = pd.DataFrame({'values': values_col})

window_size = 2
hop_size = 2
n = len(df.index)

values_moving_average = [sum(df['values'].tolist()[i - window_size : i]) / window_size for i in range(window_size, n + 1, hop_size)]
```

Then you will have the moving averages you wanted in values_moving_average list:

```
# result
[5.0, 25.0, 45.0, 65.0, 85.0]
```

Here, `window_size` is the size of the window, and hop_size is a variable you can use specify the distance between the first indices of two consecutive windows. For example if `hop_size = 1`, then we will get the average of the following windows in a list:

```
(0, 10), (10, 20), (20, 30), ..., (80, 90)
```

But, with `hop_size = 2`, we will have the following windows:

```
(0, 10), (20, 30), (40, 50), ..., (80, 90)
```